# 'attributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history' during implementing perceptual loss with pretrained VGG using keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, loss

I'm trying to implement the VGG perceptual loss for a model training for video inputs.
I implemented the perceptual loss like the recommendation in the question [AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44889187/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-history):

My mainModel looks like the following graph:
[Graph of mainModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7wDr.png)

The input size is `(bathsize, frame_num, row, col, channel)`. And I want to get the perceptual loss for the middle frame, that is, `frame_num/2`.

So, I implemented the following lossModel:

```
lossModel = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
lossModel = Model(inputs=lossModel.input,outputs=lossModel.get_layer('block3_conv4').output)
lossOut = lossModel(mainModel.output[:,frame_num/2])
fullModel = Model(mainModel.input,lossOut)
```

But I faced an error message in the line `fullModel = Model(mainModel.input, lossOut)`:

> attributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

BTW, I'm using keras version is '2.0.9'.

Could anyone help me with this?

THANKS a lot!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This most of the times means that you're doing calculations outside layers.

A keras model needs to be made of keras layers. Operations outside layers are not allowed.

Take all your calculations and put them inside `Lambda` layers: https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda

---

Here, the `mainModel.output[:,frame_num/2]` is an operation outside a layer.

Transfer it to a Lambda layer:

```
lossModel = VGG19(weights='imagenet')
lossModel = Model(inputs=lossModel.input,outputs=lossModel.get_layer('block3_conv4').output)

#you must connect lossmodel and mainmodel somewhere!!!
output = lossModel(mainModel.output)

output = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,frame_num/2])(output)

fullModel = Model(mainModel.input, output)
```

Comment: BTW, I don't think that I'm doing calculations outside layers. Are there any other possibilities for the error message?

Comment: Here is the answer. It was indeed an operation outside a layer.

Comment: Great :) -- If you consider this answers your question, please mark it as answered :)