# Concatenate input with constant vector in keras. how one define the batch_size

Tags: keras, concatenation, keras-2

As a follow-up from this question:

[Concatenate input with constant vector in keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740744/concatenate-input-with-constant-vector-in-keras/50254020?noredirect=1#comment87525510_50254020)

I am trying to use the suggested solution:

```
constant=K.variable(np.ones((1,10, 5)))
constant = K.repeat_elements(constant,rep=batch_size,axis=0)
```

And got the following Error:

```
NameError: name 'batch_size' is not defined
```

I do not see how one define within the keras model the batch_size [not explicitly] so that one can concatenate a symbolic layer and a constant layer in order to use them as an input layer.

Comment: Here a complete working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68350241/10375049

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the dynamic batch size:

```
batch_size = K.shape(your_tensor)[0]
```

But `K.repeat_elements()` doesn't accept `Tensor` values for `rep`. You can however produce the same result using [`K.tile()`](https://keras.io/backend/#tile):

```
from keras.models import *
from keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

a = Input(shape=(10, 5))
batch_size = K.shape(a)[0]
constant = K.variable(np.ones((1,10, 5)))
constant = K.tile(constant, (batch_size, 1, 1))
print(constant)
# Tensor("Tile:0", shape=(?, 10, 5), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: However now there is a problem with :

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

when calling Model.

This is the same as in: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7362

with no clear solution....

Comment: It's difficult to address your problem without further information (what are you trying to do with this code?). I'd suggest you have a llok at this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887288/attributeerror-tensor-object-has-no-attribute-keras-history-during-implem), and if it doesn't help, open a new thread.

Comment: Thanks! WIth this help and other threads I got it working.

However I would like to add that following this solution one need to add a new Input layer:

F = Input(tensor=k_constant)

and define it in the model

model = Model(inputs=[X,F], outputs=outputs)

However no such definition is needed in the model.fit(X,...

Comment: This answer may also provide help to others seeking a similar solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46466275/220338

Comment: I created a similar question mostly because I could not map this answer to my question, probably because of my inexperience. I would greatly appreciate it if you could look at my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58158620/concatenate-input-tensor-with-multiple-of-neg-1-tensors